# ¿Por qué no puedo usar .append dentro de un bucle while en Python?

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for, bucles, while

Soy un estudiante que apenas está comenzando a entender los fundamentos de Python, y esta es mi primera vez en stack overflow.

En uno de los ejercicios del curso que estoy haciendo, se me pidió crear un programa que añadiera valores a una lista mientras que su longitud fuera menor a 120. Esto se podía resolver con un bucle for in range(0,120), pero en lugar de eso se me ocurrió otra manera de hacerlo a través de un bucle while.

```
coleccion = []
contador = len(coleccion)

while contador > 120:
    coleccion.append(contador)
    contador = len(coleccion)

print(len(coleccion))
```

El problema es que, por mas que ejecuto este código, la función .append nunca agrega nada a la lista y se mantiene vacía. No entiendo cuál es el problema con la lógica de este código, lo único que se me ocurre es que append no se reconoce dentro de un bucle while, así que quisiera saber si ese es el caso y por qué ocurre de esa manera.

Tomen en consideración que solo hago esta pregunta para aprender a usar append y while, ya estoy consciente de que puedo hacer el programa que me piden en el ejercicio con un bucle for.

Comment: ¿ No será `while contador < 120:` ? Has puesto el símbolo `mayor que`.

Comment: Te felicito. Tu código es limpio, simple y organizado. Sólo erraron tus dedos, no tu mente. Se ve que tienes condiciones.

Comment: @Juanjo tienes razon, fue un error de tipeo de mi parte.

Comment: @CandidMoe de verdad gracias por tu comentario, me hizo el día! c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en tu ciclo `while`. Y es que no estás entrando en el porque el `len(coleccion)` es 0, y 0 no es mayor que 120.

Comment: Muchas gracias! No habia caido en cuenta de ese error :'D